# Why can't I use node-postgres in the browser directly?

Tags: node.js, webassembly

With libraries like node-postgres, is there a way to use Webassembly to compile it so I can use it to query data directly in the browser code?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. Web assembly can only access data (currently via javascript) through the Web Apis (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) which do not support direct database access.